# $\sum_{\Im(\rho)>0}\frac{1}{\mid{\rho-\frac{1}{2}}\mid^2}\ll \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{d(t\log t)}{t^2}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

In the book Equivalents of Riemann Hypothesis Kevin Broughan Volume 1 , pg 38, Riemann Xi function is defined as
$\xi(s)=\xi(0)\prod_{\Im(\rho)>0}(1-\frac{s(1-s)}{\rho(1-\rho)})$.
Then he says that this product above is convergent if $\sum_{\Im(\rho)>0}\frac{1}{\mid{\rho(1-\rho)}\mid}<\infty$. Then on completing the square

$$\sum_{\Im(\rho)>0}\frac{1}{\mid{\rho(1-\rho)}\mid}< \sum_{\Im(\rho)>0}\frac{1}{\mid{\rho-\frac{1}{2}}\mid^2}\ll \int_{1}^{\infty}
\frac{d(t\log t)}{t^2}.$$

I am not able to understand the last inequality involving integration

Comment: Anything said about the density of zeros ?

Comment: @reuns no nothing is said about the density of zeros. The author is trying to prove the product representation of $\xi$

Comment: Then it must be the argument principle $\sum_{\Im(\rho)>0}\frac{1}{\mid{\rho-\frac{1}{2}}\mid^2} \ll \sum_{\Im(\rho)>0}\frac{1}{(\rho-\frac{1}{2})^2}\ll \oint \frac1{s^2}\frac{\zeta'(s+1/2)}{\zeta(s+1/2)} ds$. The latter contour integral is on two vertical lines outside of the critical strip so we have estimates for $\zeta'/\zeta$ from the Dirichlet series representation and the functional equation.

Comment: @reuns Argument principle?

Comment: I meant the residue theorem (this is also how we deduce the density of zeros). The $d(t\log t)$ in your integral is from differentiating the Stirling formula for $\log \Gamma(\sigma+it)$

Comment: @reuns Can you please write it as an answer. Please

Comment: I don't know the level of details you need, you should probably look at proofs of the density of zeros (all the books on $\zeta(s)$ are on http://93.174.95.27/ ) to see the exact complex analysis tools you need

Comment: @reuns Is the inequality also true if we add one more condition that $\Re(\rho)<1/2$?

Comment: @reuns Is this true ?$ \sum_{\Im(\rho)>0,\Re(\rho)<1/2}\frac{1}{\mid{\rho-\frac{1}{2}}\mid^2}《 \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{d(tlogt)}{t^2}$

Comment: @Gary Any hints for the problem?

Comment: @reuns Please reply

Comment: It should follow from the fact that the number of zeros in the critical strip whose imaginary part in absolute value is at most $t$, is $\ll t\log t$. Just write the sum as an integral using this zero counting function.

Comment: @Gary The OP said this isn't proven/assumed in the book, and my approach does prove it.

Comment: @reuns Then please write it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N(t)$ be the number of zeros in the critical strip whose imaginary part is positive and is at most $t$. It is known that $N(t) \ll t\log t$. Thus
$$
\sum\limits_{0 < \Im (\rho ) \le T} {\frac{1}{{\left| {\rho  - \frac{1}{2}} \right|^2 }}}  = \int_1^T {\frac{{dN(t)}}{{\left| {t - \frac{1}{2}} \right|^2 }}}  \ll \int_1^T {\frac{{d(t\log t)}}{{t^2 }}}
$$
($N(t)=0$ for $0<t<1$). Now let $T\to +\infty$.

Comment: Thanks. Is this true ? $ \sum_{\Im(\rho)>0,\Re(\rho)<1/2}\frac{1}{\mid{\rho-\frac{1}{2}}\mid^2}《 \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{d(tlogt)}{t^2}$

Comment: Please answer this and i will give you a check mark

Comment: Isn't it rue that $
\sum\limits_{\Im \rho  > 0,\Re \rho  < 1/2} {\frac{1}{{\left| {\rho  - \frac{1}{2}} \right|^2 }}}  < \sum\limits_{\Im \rho  > 0} {\frac{1}{{\left| {\rho  - \frac{1}{2}} \right|^2 }}} 
$? :)

Comment: I think it is true. Thank you so much dear.